# Copy file to another folder with REST API

Tags: rest, file, onedrive-for-business

I'm trying to copy a file located in user's personal folder (OneDrive Pro) using REST API. The resulting link seems to become too long and server returns 400  BadRequest: The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.

Url looks like this (HTTP verb is POST):

```
https://<company>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<user>_<company>_onmicrosoft_com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/<user>_<company>_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/<Folder>/<Folder with guid-like name>/<filename>.pdf')/copyto(strnewurl='/personal/<user>_<company>_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/<Same folder>/<another guid-like name>/<same filename>.pdf',boverwrite=true)
```

Any help or advice on how to overcome this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a maximum 256 character limit in SharePoint for REST URLs - reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/dn292556.aspx

However URL parameters are not included in the length-restriction, so can be used to get round this limit. Here is an example of using URL parameters to bypass this limit:

```
https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_account_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl(@v)/startupload(uploadId=guid'38acfb37-ccd5-4ac1-961d-090ce1ed9d6f')?@v='/personal/user_account_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Test/7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso.001'
```

For a little more information you can see this post:

[The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value. REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125737/the-length-of-the-url-for-this-request-exceeds-the-configured-maxurllength-value?rq=1)