# The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value. REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, console-application

I was wondering if someone could help, or am I missing something. In the articles found here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FileStartUpload

They refer to using the `/getfilebyserverrelativeurl`.  When I build my request and try and make a `HttpWebRequest` I get

> The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value

in the webresponse.

I'm making these requests from a console application against Office 365/SharePoint Online.

The url length is is 305 in this test case.

This is the code I am using

```
            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(resourceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Credentials = _credentials;
            request.CookieContainer = _cookieContainter;
            request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", _formDigest);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Timeout = 3600000;
            request.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
            request.ContentLength = incomingStream.Length;
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            using (var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
                incomingStream.CopyTo(reqStream);
            }

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

When its caught by the WebException and I read the exception response all I get is this
"The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value."

This is the resourceUrl:

> https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_account_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/personal/user_account_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Test/7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso.001')/startupload(uploadId=guid'38acfb37-ccd5-4ac1-961d-090ce1ed9d6f')

Comment: Is your entire request URL longer than 2000 characters?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using?

Comment: Added more details to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
getFileByServerRelativeUrl
```

you can use

```
GetFileById or GetFolderById
```

To upload a new file, you can use the below url

/_api/web/GetFolderById('UniqueId')/Files/add(url='filename',overwrite=true)

Reference: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I've tried that. I've used that for other calls. Trying to get the file start upload to work which is the link in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

In case it helps, we had a similar (but not exact-same) situation.  The URL *parameters* are not included in the length-restriction (at least not this restriction), so we changed our URL to be like so (to edit the original example) :

```
https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_account_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl(@v)/startupload(uploadId=guid'38acfb37-ccd5-4ac1-961d-090ce1ed9d6f')?@v='/personal/user_account_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Test/7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso.001'
```

That appears to be working as expected.

Be aware of the 260 char max path limitation in general, though.  If you try and add a file[name] to a folder and that total length exceeds the limit, you have a different problem with a known SP limitation.

Best of luck!

-AJ

Comment: +1 for this answer - should be the marked answer.

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: Really awesome tricky logic you posted, many thanks to you

Comment: Works with minimal changes to original code, nice!

Comment: you dah man user5346346436

Answer (score -2):

Change the method from "GET" to "POST" and that will resolve the URL length issue.

Comment: In this case it needs to be a post.

Comment: then you have to include the urls in the body of the request not on the url itself.